# Why feature can't be edited in QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, qgis-3, line, editing, features

I am working with shapefiles in QGIS. At the moment I am editing a shapefile with line objects.

When drawing a new line it appeared in a different manner then set in the layer properties. Now I can`t even delete the new drawed line. The layer I was editing contained the broken blue lines. The new drawed line is the one in the red circle. Has anyone an idea what I did wrong?

[image]

Comment: On your screenshot, the toolbars above the map canvas are missing - can you include a screenshot including this? Does close and re-open QGIS help to solve the problem? Where is the layer saved: do have writing permission in this folder?

Comment: Did you finish drawing the line? Because right now it looks like you didn't.

Comment: What QGIS version are you using? There were some troubles with those temporary drawings that were fixed in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36301